# Elasticsearch : delete index and recreate same index result in incorrect data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use elasticsearch-2.3.2

I created my index  http://localhost:9200/github_inactivusr-2017.03.21

The command

```
curl http://localhost:9200/github_inactivusr-2017.03.21/_search
```

indicates I have a total of 7650 entries in my index

```
{
  "took" : 40,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 7650,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
...
}
```

I delete this index

```
 curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9200/github_inactivusr-2017.03.21
```

I do get the message

> {"acknowledged":true}

When I execute

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```

I get

```
red    open stats-new_format_membership-2016.08.12    5 1
red    open stats-json3-jira-users-2017.07.13         5 1
yellow open github_activusr-2017.03.21               5 1  80495 0  16.6mb  16.6mb
yellow open github_activusr-2017.07.24               5 1  34697 0   9.3mb   9.3mb
```

The index github_inactivusr-2017.03.21 is no longer listed

I then recreate the index "github_inactivusr-2017.03.21" (exactly the same name and same mapping) again with 2550 entries

However, when I use the command `curl http://localhost:9200/github_inactivusr-2017.03.21/_search`,
I still get a total of 7650 entries.

After recreating the index, if I execute the command :

```
 curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices
```

I get

```
red    open stats-new_format_membership-2016.08.12    5 1
red    open stats-json3-jira-users-2017.07.13         5 1
yellow open github_activusr-2017.03.21               5 1  80495 0  16.6mb  16.6mb
yellow open github_activusr-2017.07.24               5 1  34697 0   9.3mb   9.3mb
yellow open github_inactivusr-2017.03.21             5 1   7650 0   1.6mb   1.6mb
```

It is as if the index was not properly removed. Even if I stop and restart elasticsearch before recreating the index, I get this behaviour. 
It is as if there is a cache or whatsoever that does not get rid of the data.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Can you provide the result of the following command before and after deleting your index: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`?

Comment: OK I will edit the question

Comment: Did you execute the `_cat/indices` command just after you've deleted the index? Also can you show the exact command you're using to delete the index?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause.
The problem was related to the logstash configuration file that I used.
It was reinjecting 3 times the same data, which explains the 7650 (2550 * 3)

Sorry about the time and thanks @Val